# Removing a specific group using regular expression

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that removes the IP Address from multiple different texts groups

I am using XML when calling my regexp.

```
<field name="access_device" count="17" delimiter="{_csv_}" edit="re=(\w+---\w+|\w+-\w+|\w+)(?=[-\n])"case="upper" allow-blank="yes" />
```

Text I receive from client below:

```
Future_7330
Future_7340
SNANTXWA010153021-76.200.41.6-MULTI AND MGT
SNAZTXSI01HUT1011-76.200.41.30-Unicast
SNANTXW010153021-76.200.41.6-UNICAST
IPDSLAM-HXC101260-71-71.149.53.62
CHVWTXGT---01CAB101A-71.149.53.58
ATASTXADOL0010BAY111-71.149.52.41-MULTI AND MGT
```

so my end result I would like it to look like this below:

```
Future_7330
Future_7340
SNANTXWA010153021-MULTI AND MGT          <----- (-MULTI AND MGT can bee keep or remove what ever makes it easy for the reg exp)
SNAZTXSI01HUT1011-Unicast                 <-----(-UNICAST can bee keep or remove what ever makes it easy for the reg exp)
SNANTXW010153021-UNICAST                  <-----(-UNICAST can bee keep or remove what ever makes it easy for the reg exp)
IPDSLAM-HXC101260
CHVWTXGT---01CAB101A
ATASTXADOL0010BAY111-MULTI AND MGT        <------(-MULTI AND MGT can bee keep or remove what ever makes it easy for the reg exp)
```

Comment: You want to process the xml file with this content ?

Comment: yes i usually have something like this `<field name="access_device" count="17" delimiter="{_csv_}" edit="re=(\w+---\w+|\w+-\w+|\w+)(?=[-\n])"case="upper" allow-blank="yes" />` regular expression in xml.

Comment: What language are you using. Also I notice you mention XML but I don't see any XML in your example. How is XML involved?

Comment: I edit my question and added the xml part that does the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to capture thre required text:

```
(.*?(?:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})).*)
```

Try the same at the link: https://regex101.com/r/kO8rF7/2

Comment: Same as above, It only captures the IPv4 address, I am looking for something that captures everything else except the IPv4

Comment: It captures two groups. One the IP address and the other being the remaining text.

Comment: when I ran your regular expression it append the IP at the end. this was one of the output `ABHGMIMNG00010123112-ANM-1-107.208.30.6107.208.30.6`

Comment: You just need to use the first group as the final output. Can you use something like $0 or \0 to get the first regex matched group in xml

Comment: I can try but how would the syntax look like, I am terrible at reg exp only know the basics.

Comment: `<field name="access_device" count="17" delimiter="{_csv_}" edit="re=(.*?(?:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})).*)" case="upper" allow-blank="yes" />`

Comment: I have not worked with XML regex before, but on general regex principle can you try : edit="re=/(.*?(?:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})).*)/$0/"

Comment: I just finished running it, it looks like it did not parse anything.

Comment: You might want to play around with this and try just this once more: (.*?(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this regex to find IPv4 addresses a couple of days ago: https://regex101.com/r/dA7sJ5/3

```
/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/g
```

Use it with whatever language you like to do a simple regex replace with "" and remove the IP addresses from your text.

Comment: this only captures the IPv4 address, I am looking for something that captures everything else except the IPv4